# How do i customize the name of the job?

Tags: hadoop

When a Job is submitted it is given an ID say job_200904211745_0018 in Hadoop.

But for some reason i want to submit it with ID say "job1".
How can i do that ?

Arun

Comment: You probably can't. The job system probably requires a unique identifier, built in a way it knows about.

Comment: You can't change job_id, but you can change job name, are you using pure map/reduce or pig/hive ?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation at http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID.html it says

> Applications should never construct ... JobID strings, but rather
>   use appropriate constructors or [forName(String)](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) method.

How exactly the `forName` function operates, not sure; haven't used it myself.

If you want to construct a 'Name' for specific jobs, there is the JobName, which can be set by the job's [`setJobName`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setJobName%28java.lang.String%29). This is what I use to identify what the job is when I review the M/R Admin page.

Your actual reasons, instead of "for some reason", may help the hive-mind to come up with other options, or maybe someone faced the same reasoning and has a solution they can share.

The more background and information about the issue you are encountering that you share tends to allows more detailed responses with more applicable solutions.